# How to get OnClicked event at multiple actors

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Using the OnClicked delegate I'm able to receive and act on click events, but when multiple actors overlap and would receive an event, only one receives the event and "swallows" it, the others not receiving the event.

I'm wondering if there is an alternative built into UE4 that would let all actors under the mouse pointer to receive the event, or a way of allowing one actor to "pass through" the event so that it could fall through to the next candidate.

Currently I have a simple component doing the following:

```
void UMoverShaker::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    GetOwner()->FindComponentByClass<UStaticMeshComponent>()
        ->OnClicked.AddDynamic(this, &UMoverShaker::OnClicked);
}

void UMoverShaker::OnClicked(UPrimitiveComponent* ClickedComp, FKey ButtonClicked)
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("click clack %d"), GetOwner()->GetUniqueID());
}
```

Comment: You can try to use the Multi Line Trace functionality. When the mouse clicks, trace from camera according to mouse pointer location, it should give you the result.

Comment: @goose_lake yeah, that's what I was afraid of, thanks for the confirmation